# The Drawer is transparent

Tags: flutter

The drawer's background is transparent. I have tried to hot reload the entire code which i wrote from scratch again, yet it didn't work.

```
drawer: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 100.0),
            child: Text('Hi!'),
            curve: Curves.easeInCubic,
          ),
          ListTile(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.donut_small),
            title: Text(
              'Home',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Reference Image

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should use `Drawer` widget as a parent of your `ListView`

```
drawer: 
     Drawer(
        child: ListView(
           ....
```

More info here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer

Answer (score 0):

You are using `DrawerHeader` incorrectly. `DrawerHeader` is only the top portion of the `Drawer` that you want to open. You should use it to set a title for that `Drawer` and probably a different background color.
Try this instead:

```
         Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 100.0),
                child: Text('Hi!'),
                curve: Curves.easeInCubic,
              ),
              ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
                leading: Icon(Icons.home),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.donut_small),
                title: Text(
                  'Home',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```